# Error obtaining unique transport key from ORTE

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I was trying to run a test case for Espresso 5.2.0 using the parallel version. While running the tests I got the following error message:"Error obtaining unique transport key from ORTE (orte_precondition_transports not present in
the environment)."
I searched online for this error and found out this is an error with the MPI, although I am not really sure. Can someone please help me out with this! Possible work around for this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Although some of the core Open MPI developers roam here, your problem would be taken notice of much quicker if you post it to the [Open MPI User mailing list](http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/ompi.php).

Answer (score 3):

Try to Set export OMPI_MCA_mtl=^psm, might solve your problem.